# Failing using startx to launch different desktops

Tags: raspbian-stretch, terminal, startx

I am trying to use startx to launch different desktops according to an argument using `case...esac`

This is my .xinitrc

```
mate(){
    (sleep 5 && conky) &
    mate-session
} 

case $1 in
    d2) i3;;
     *) mate;;
esac
```

When I use `startx` launches by default mate (as it should be). However, when using `startx d2` nothing happens.

What I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

I've just found out that using `xinit d2` it launches the desktop environment but not with `startx d2`

Comment: Do you have `i3` installed properly? Can you launch it manually?

Comment: Yes. If I use `startx i3` it launches perfectly fine.

Comment: what if you try changing `i3` in the script to `startx i3`? It's redundant, but it could work...

Comment: Nope. Still the same.

Comment: Weird. What about adding some debug messages. Add one at the top that says `echo ".xinitrc running"` and then replace the `i3` with `echo "running i3"` and then see what happens when you type `startx d2`.

Comment: Nothing. In fact, I've removed everything from .xinitrc and added only `echo  ".xinitrc running" ` and nothing happend. Just launches Xorg and then returns to cli.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91013/discussion-between-scitronboy-and-potato).